# Cannot include a file in php

Tags: php

I am running the code below in some if/else statements, I have a weird issue in the same file this exact code below works fine, however in another area if it is called I get this error;

```
Warning: include() [function.include]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in C:\webserver\htdocs\processing\process.friends.php on line 168

Warning: include(http://localhost/index.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in C:\webserver\htdocs\processing\process.friends.php on line 168

$_SESSION['sess_msg'] = 'Please Enter the Correct Security Code';
$_GET["friendid"] = $friendid;
$_GET["p"] = 'mail.captcha';
$_GET["f"] = 'friend';
include ("index.php");
exit;
```

And just to clarify I am njot trying to run this code 2 times at the SAME time, it's more like this; Not just like this but you get the point that they are not run at the same time

```
if(something){
   run the code above
}else{
   run the code above
}
```

If it matters, I am currently running a LAMP setup on a windows PC

Answer (score 10, accepted):

remove the "http://localhost" part of your code.  As a rule of thumb, when you include your own files, you should include them from your file system.

```
include "./index.php";
```

Comment: yeah that is just a test code, it has no affect on it working or not though

Comment: Looks like it did fix it, I must of overlooked this before, weird how it's usually the simplest issues that take the most time to fix, usually from overlooking them because they seem simple, thanks

Comment: excellent!  Glad I could help.  Yeah, it is funny how that is true, but you learn alot in the process.  Keep going and you'll be a pro in no time.

Comment: Upvoted both your answer and your comment because of your general supportiveness. =)

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the **http://localhost/** part and you'll be okay.

Comment: that worked, weird, I was just trying every file path possible to get it to work, I don't know how I overlooked that

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't kow the answer to your question, though I do have to ask why you feel the need to include a URL based file?

`include('http://whatever.com/');` can be EXTREMELY dangerous.

If you're just trying to output the HTML generated from that, I'd suggest you do something like `echo file_get_contents('http://some/url');`. If you're trying to include PHP code, use the system path

Comment: actually it will be (index.php) it just has apth because I am trying every way possible to get it to work right now

Answer (score 0):

Are they EXACTLY the same? Could you post both versions of the code?

I can also recommend not doing an include('http://...'); This will make PHP to an HTTP request to your webserver, and grab the result. You might be a bit better off just doing include('index.php');, if this is possible for your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Is [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled in php.ini?